# linux command line rename all files with supplied argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell

trying to rename all files in a directory to `$arg[1] + number of file`.

for example these files:

```
gfdgfdh.jpg  
fgdsyugfs.jpg  
gfyudsfuds.jpg
```

will become the following when i do `sh myscript.sh dog` at the command line:

```
dog0.jpg
dog1.jpg
dog2.jpg
```

Here is the code I have so far, the regex works because if it try the `rename` command on one file from the command line it works.

```
#! /bin/sh
COUNTER=0
PREFIX=$1
for i in *.jpg
do
        rename 's/.*[^.jpg]/${PREFIX}${COUNTER}/' $i
        COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

The error I get is

```
Global symbol "$PREFIX" requires explicit package name at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Comment: That regex doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you put `$PREFIX` inside `''`, which doesn't expand it, but passes it to the Perl program `rename`, which in turn seems to evaluate the pattern as Perl code.

Another mistake in your script is `COUNTER=COUNTER+1`. The shell just doesn't work that way. Try this instead (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh
prefix=$1

count=0
for f in *.jpg; do
    mv "$f" "$prefix$count".jpg
    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Comment: thanks this works and shown me a few things i hadnt done before

Comment: `expr` isn't necessary: `((count++))` is all you need.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: the OP is using `/bin/sh` as the shell, which on many platforms (including Ubuntu) is not Bash but a stripped-down POSIX shell. `((count++))` doesn't work in POSIX.

Comment: It's true that `((count++))` is not POSIX, [but `count=$((count + 1))` is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04). `expr` is only needed in [ancient shells](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html). I missed the OP's shebang - the question is tagged [tag:bash].

Answer (score 1):

rename accepts a perl program/expression and in your case the $PREFIX is interpreted as a variable.

rename is a tool to bulk rename files, you are using it to rename only a file. A better approach would be:

```
PREFIX=dog; 
rename  "s#[^/]*.jpg#'$PREFIX' . \$main::C++ . '.jpg'#e" tmp/*.jpg
```

Comment: I don't think the parentheses are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

with "rename" command

```
rename 's/.*/dog$N.jpg/' *.jpg
```